# Find subdifferential of function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \max(1, \exp(x^2))$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

By subdifferential I mean the set of all subderivatives, where the subderivative at point $x$ is a real number $c$ such that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ it is the case that:
$$f(y) - f(x) \geq c(y-x)$$

It seems to me that for $x < 0$ it is just $0$ and for $x > 0$ it is $2x\exp(x^2)$. So I am interested in subdifferential at point $x = 0$.

So I have to find $c$ such that for all $y$
$$f(y) - f(x) \geq c(y -x) \\
f(y) - 1 \geq cy \\$$

$f(y)$ has to be greater or equal to $1$.

Is there other subdifferential at point $x = 0$ then $c = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general at a breakpoint the subgradient is the convex hull of the left and right derivative. In this case you have $f(y) - 1 \geq cy$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, so
\begin{align}
0 \geq cy \qquad \forall y \leq 0 \\
\exp(y^2) - 1 \geq cy  \qquad \forall y \geq 0
\end{align}
The first inequality gives $c \geq 0$. The second inequality gives $c \leq [\exp(y^2) - \exp(0)] / y$, which if you take the limit of $y \downarrow 0$ gives $c \leq 0$, so $c=0$.